# How do i create a common heading for two pivot items?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

i have two pivot items , i want both of them to have a common heading , that is some part of heading would be seen in pivot item 1 then when the user would sweep in right direction then remaining part of the heading would be seen in pivot item 3.Can anyone suggest a logic for this ?

```
<!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="first">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="second">
            <!--Double line list no text wrapping-->
            <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineThree}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,-6,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

Comment: If you could update your post with an image of what you want, that would be very useful

Comment: dont have enough reoutation for it :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pivot items must have one different header from each other, that is by design .
You can use instead a Panorama control.